# Cannot Insert data from C# into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert data into a `.mdf` SQL Server file, but when I want to see data that I insert. It wasn't happen. I use local database for work.

```
private SqlConnection connection;
private SqlCommand command;
private string sql;

private void frmNewEmp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conStr = @"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Payrolldatabase.mdf;";

    connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
       connection.Open();
    }
}

private void InsertData()
{
    sql = @"INSERT INTO Employee(EID, EName, EAdd, ESSID, ETel, EDatesub, ESalary) VALUES(@id, @name, @add, @ssid, @tel, @date, @sal)";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.CommandText = sql;

    AddParamterValues();

    MessageBox.Show("Add complete");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not executing your command anywhere. *(Assuming you have correctly attached parameters)*

You need

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And also you need an open connection for the database.

Just noticed that you are opening the connection on `Load` and then not closing it. It is not the best way to do DB stuff, **Open Database connection as Late as possible and close as early as possible** should be the rule.

Consider enclosing your connection object in `using`statement *(like you did with command object)* and then use that connection for the Command

Comment: Connection is opened on load, but never closed